Finding the conjugate operator of the following operator
Let $A$ be linear operator from $l^2$ to $l^2$ such that $Ax =y^0 \cdot \sum_{1}^{\infty}{x_k} $ , where $y^0 \in l^2$ — fixed element.
Show, that conjugate operator $A^*$ exists and find it. Show, that $A^{**}$ doesn't exist.
My attempt:
$(x',Ax) = (A^{*}x',x)$
$\sum_{1}^{\infty} \bar{x'_k} \cdot Sy^0_k = \sum_{1}^{\infty} \bar{z_k} \cdot x_k$ , where $z_k$ is $k$-th element of sequence $A^{*}x'$ , $S = \sum_1^{\infty} x_k$
Let $z_k = \sum_{1}^{\infty} \bar{x'_k} \cdot y^0_k \; \; \;$ ($z_k$ doesn't depend on $k$)
Then, $S \sum_{1}^{\infty} \bar{x'_k} \cdot y^0_k = \sum_1^{\infty} \bar{x'_k} \cdot y^0_k \cdot \sum_1^{\infty} x_k = S \sum_{1}^{\infty} \bar{x'_k} \cdot y^0_k$
However, $A^*x'$ then doesn't belong to $l^2$

For $y^0\neq 0$ the operator $A$ is defined on $D(A)=\{x\in \ell^2\,:\, \sum x_k\ {\rm is\ convergent}\}.$ The domain is dense as it contains the sequences with finitely many nonzero terms. The domain of the adjoint operator consists of all elements $z\in \ell^2$ such that the functional
$D(A)\ni x\mapsto \langle Ax,z\rangle $ is bounded. However
$$ \langle Ax,z\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left [ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\right ]y_k^0\overline{z_k}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\,\langle y^0,z\rangle $$ Such functional is bounded if and only if $z\perp y^0,$ i.e. $D(A^*)=(y^0)^\perp. $ Moreover for $z\in D(A^*) $ we get $\langle Ax,z\rangle =0,$  thus $A^*z=0.$ The domain of $A^*$ is not dense, hence we cannot construct $A^{**}.$
